# Erro ao fazer consulta com o EntityFramework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Estou tendo um problema com uma requisição, no controller quando faço a consulta na tabela produtos aparece a seguinte mensagem ao debugar, eu clico em um icone e não retorna nenhum dado, mas a tabela possui dados e eu coloquei para retornar todos:

> Local : The Function Evaluation requires all threads to run
>
> SQL : The Function Evaluation requires all threads to run

**View**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function carregarProdutos(id) {

        $list = $("#produto-target");
        console.log(id);
        $.ajax({
            url: "GetProdutos",
            type: "POST",
            data: { id: id },
            dataType: 'json',
            traditional: true,
            success: function (result) {
                $list.empty();
                $.each(result, function (item) {
                    $list.append('<option value="' + item["produtoid"] + '"> ' + item["nome"] + ' </option>');
                });
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Algo deu errado.");
            }
        });
    }      
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Compra</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FornecedorId, "Fornecedor", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("FornecedorId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FornecedorId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CartegoriaId, "Categoria", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("CategoriaId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @onchange = "carregarProdutos(this.value)" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CartegoriaId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProdutoId, "Produto", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("ProdutoId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @id = "produto-target" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProdutoId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Valor, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Valor, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Valor, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Quantidade, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Quantidade, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Quantidade, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar Compra" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Voltar", "Index")
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("GetProdutos/id")]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetProdutos(int? id)
{
    var listaProdutos = new List<Produto>();


    if(id == null)
    {
        return Json("Não há produtos");
    }

    listaProdutos = await GetProdutosPorIdCategoriaAsync((int)id);

    return Json(listaProdutos);
}

public async Task<List<Produto>> GetProdutosPorIdCategoriaAsync(int idCategoria)
{
    return await db.Produtos.ToListAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver colocando essa propriedade -> db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false. O código ficou Assim:

```
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult> GetProdutos(int? id)
        {
            db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

            if(id == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound("Erro com a categoria.");
            }

            var lista = await GetProdutosPorIdCategoriaAsync((int)id);

            return Json(lista, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Veja se isso resolve:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("GetProdutos/id")]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetProdutos(int? id)
{
    var listaProdutos = new List<Produto>();

    var task = Task.Run(() => Json("Não há produtos"));
    if(id == null)
    {
        return await task;
    }

    listaProdutos = await GetProdutosPorIdCategoriaAsync((int)id);
    task = Task.Run(() => Json(listaProdutos));

    return await task;
}
```

Não cheguei a testar o código, se necessário volto aqui pra editar.

Comment: Não rolou. List não possui ToList e nem ToListAsync

Comment: @DiegoAquino, no debug o erro ocorre nessa linha: return await db.Produtos.ToListAsync();?

Comment: Sim, exatamente.

Comment: @DiegoAquino Editei a resposta, veja se funciona.

Comment: George, eu consegui resolver alterando essa propriedade da configuração ->  db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false. Agradeço sua ajuda.

Comment: @DiegoAquino, você pode colocar outra resposta aqui com a solução que encontrou e aceitar ela como pra sua pergunta. Pode ser útil pra mais pessoas. :)